# How to display two not associated models on one page via admin interface?

Tags: django, model, django-admin

I have two models, not connected by ForeignKey. I would to display them on one page in admin interface, in the way like inlines in Django.

I can't associate PostFile with Post, because uploaded medias should be available to every Post which was and will be created in future. I have no idea what I can do if inlines are unavailable.

```
class Post(models.Model):

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published')
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique_for_date='publish_date', blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    content = MarkdownxField()
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_update_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = [
            '-publish_date'
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                       args=[
                           self.publish_date.strftime('%Y'),
                           self.publish_date.strftime('%m'),
                           self.publish_date.strftime('%d'),
                           self.slug
                       ])

    #https://github.com/neutronX/django-markdownx/issues/83

    def formatted_markdown(self):
        return markdownify(self.content)


class PostFile(models.Model):

    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    file_object = models.FileField(upload_to='post_files/')
    file_upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.file_name:
            self.file_name = self.file_object.name
        super(PostFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def file_url(self):
        return self.file_object.url

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file_name
```

I would to receive in output a Post model admin page, where on the bottom I have listed all PostFile objects. This will give me easy and fast acces to PostFile-object url on media folder. I don't want each time to open new tab, and to go to PostFile model admin page to check url of object.

Comment: You can use custom Django Forms and pass the same to that model admin.

`class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CourseForm`